# Scopes is not missing constant Product?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scope

I want to use 'scope' in my project.

i create a folder under lib, see

[image: the directory structure]

The file 'product.rb' include some methods, like

```
module Scopes::Product
  #TODO: change this to array pairs so we preserve order?

  SCOPES = {
    # Scopes for selecting products based on taxon
    :taxon => {
      :taxons_name_eq => [:taxon_name],
      :in_taxons => [:taxon_names],
    },
    # product selection based on name, or search
    :search => {
      :in_name => [:words],
      :in_name_or_keywords => [:words],
      :in_name_or_description => [:words],
      :with_ids => [:ids]
    },
...
```

I use it in my model 'product.rb'

```
include ::Scopes::Product
```

error message:

```
pry(main)> Product
ArgumentError: Scopes is not missing constant Product!
from /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:479:in `load_missing_constant'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try namespacing this way..

```
module Scopes
  module Product
      ....
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but it cannot work. Please see the new error      LoadError: Expected /home/tanglin/fincloud/lib/scopes/product.rb to define Product        I know a method to make it work, just to change the file's name, and use the normal module.  But i want to understand what's mean 'module Scopes::Product', how does it work?  The source code was got from the opensource 'Spree'

Answer (score 2):

Did you happen to add `lib/scopes` to your autoload dirs? You will get this message if Ruby is trying to autoload something but gets something that is already defined. For example, if it tries to get a definition for `Product`, loads `lib/scopes/product.rb` and all it gets is `Scopes::Product`. The autoload mechanism is not so clever, it doesn't try to resolve things or exhaustively search the trees.

Answer (score 0):

use `Product::ORDERING` or `Product::SCOPES` instead of `Scopes::Product::ORDERING` or `Scopes::Product::SCOPES`